# Help with SQL structure for creating a schedule of notifications

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hi I have the following problem and I am trying to work out what is the best way to solve.

I have a table say called [Kpi] and the data would be like this:-

```
[ContractId]    [KpiId]      [NotificationIntervalInMonths]
 1000           1               3
 1000           2               5
```

I have a [Contract] table which contains:-

```
[ContractId]    [StartDate]     [EndDate]
 1000           1/Nov/2009      4/Apr/2011
```

I am after a way to show a schedule of notifications for when the Kpi are due to notify a user between the start and end date of the contract e.g. The structure above would create the following columns/rows:-

```
[ContractId]    [KpiId]      [NotificationDate]
   1000            1            1/Feb/2009
   1000            1            1/May/2010
   1000            1            1/Aug/2010
   1000            1            1/Nov/2010
   1000            1            1/Feb/2011 
   1000            2            1/Apr/2010
   1000            2            1/Sep/2010
   1000            2            1/Feb/2011
```

I first of all thought that I would create a lookup table that got populated a every time I inserted a new Kpi, this seems feasible and may seem the best approach.

My business logic dictates that the [NotificationIntervalInMonths] can't be changed, however the [EndDate] of a contract can change. This means that I would have to add/delete records in the lookup table based on the new contract [EndDate] and to me this seems a bit messy.

So this leads me to my question, is there a pure SQL approach that can get me a schedule of notifications without creating a look up table? Cursors are not allowed :P but I hoping CTE's would work here.

If I have not given enough information then please ask.

Comment: I have a solution that is based on a recursive CTE. This CTE is however only works if my notification interval for each Kpi is a multiple of 3. This is OK for me as it stands because my Business Logic has this constraint defined. However it would be nice to solve this if my interval was set to anything (for future proofing), so if anyone can help then that would be great. I can post my solution if any body wishes.

Comment: Solved it at last, can cater for any interval period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer, if any body could review it/enhance it then please let me know...

```
declare @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime
set @startDate = '01/Nov/2009'
set @endDate = '04/Apr/2011'

declare @kpi table(kpiid int, interval int)
insert into @kpi 
select 1, 3 
union select 2, 5
--union select 3, 9 
--union select 4, 12

;with mycte(i, d, interval, p, kpiid) as
(
 select i = 1, d=@startDate, Interval, 0, kpiid from @kpi 
 union all
 select 
  i = i + 1, 
  dateAdd(mm, i, @StartDate), 
  interval,  
  case when (datediff(mm, @StartDate, m.d)) % interval = (interval - 1) then 1 else 0 end,
  m.kpiid
 from 
  mycte m where m.d < @EndDate
)
select * from mycte where p = 1 and d <=@EndDate order by kpiid, d
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table valued function that accepts your two date ranges and that will return the 1st date in each month in that range. Then join to that function in a query. Sorry, can't give more detail, someone is hassling me on Skype (oh, it's you!). :)

Comment: It certainly is a possibility, I will have a think about this. I suppose I would need a calendar lookup table to pull back multiple rows....

Comment: No you don't, I'll create some SQL then. Although a calendar lookup would be faster (and you could include stuff like 'avoid december as it is a big booze up).